# How to delay locking of my Mac when I am not using it

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, mac

Right now, it gets locked in 3-4 minutes. How do I delay the locking?
I am using snow leopard

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Lion, there's a setting in System Preferences under Security & Privacy asking how long after sleep or the screen saver begins is the password required.

[image]

Comment: After I click the lock to make changes, my "Require password" is disabled. Perhaps this is a custom change in my office provided laptop?

Comment: @xyz After you click the lock, click the "Advanced.." button at the bottom, that has a text box where you can enter number of minutes of inactivity to trigger a logout. Maybe that's what u are looking for...

Comment: mtk that's not what @xyz is referring, it's the "Require password___after sleep..." line which is disabled, I have the same issue, probably because it's a company laptop too.

Answer (score 18):

If anyone gets this problem you wont solve it with the above. You will need to go to system preferences and then energy saving and then set the time-out for battery and plug-in use. Spotlight (Cmd + Space) and enter Energy Saving. Once you're in you'll find it :)

Comment: The question was how to delay the locking (i.e. requirement of username + password).  What you've described is how to change the delay before the screen turns off.  That's something else entirely.  The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: This Answer is not exactly what the question is asking. But this solved my problem. So up voted. :D

Comment: I was looking for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1 select system preferences**

[image]

**Step 2 select baterry**

[image]

**Step 3 adjust the scroller "turn off display after"**

[image]

Comment: No this does not lock the computer it just turns the screen off and you can just hit any key to use it again. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268547/237 for the correct panel in System Preferences

Answer (score 2):

In macOS Sierra,

Click on apple icon Left top corner -> System Preferences..

Click on Security & Privacy Icon

Click on General tab.

Now you can increase or decrease locking time.
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is get from support.apple.com,

Turn off your display or put it to sleep

Choose **System Preferences from the Apple menu**, then **click Energy Saver**.
Use the **slider to choose the time** of inactivity. If you set your display to turn off before the screen saver starts, the screen saver won't start after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this helpful app for easy toggling between locking or not: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12